# How can I disable(remove) wpautop (wptexturize, convert_chars) for specific shortcodes only?

Tags: shortcode

I am having a trouble in disabling formatting for specific shortcode.
For example, I have:

```
[MyTag]"hi"[/MyTag]
```

However, the output is `“hi“` (note the formatted quotes). I want to disable any kind of formatting (and keep untouched) everything for that shortcode. But the below:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
```

completely removes formatting from content and all other shortcodes. I ONLY want to affect  `[MyTag]` shortcodes only. How can i achieve that?

Comment: I don't know if there is a reliable way, but honestly, if you feel that you need to do this then my feeling is that you're using the editor 'wrong'. It is not a code editor. If you need this level of control over your markup then you should look into custom templates with custom fields, or developing Gutenberg blocks.

Comment: What does `[MyTag]` do? Can we see its code? What problem does this solve? Any and all context/code is welcome

Comment: @TomJNowell I've updated question.